# Interrupt handler starts behaving unexpectedly when scheduler runs

Tags: embedded, c++, freertos, nordic

I have an IRQ handler that gets fired upon receiving a character over serial, and everything is fine until I run a FreeRTOS scheduler inside main, and now what I see is IRQ handler still getting invoked but it isn't behaving as expected: the following API isn't disabling the event register as it would if the scheduler wasn't running, resulting in the IRQ handler getting invoked again and again

```c
pInstance->setEvent(NRF_UART_EVENT_RXDRDY, 0);
```

```c
// logger.cpp
TaskHandle_t Logger::loggerThread;
TaskHandle_t Logger::taskMsgBuffer;
StreamBufferHandle_t Logger::streamBuffer;

typedef enum
{
    totalStreamBufferBytes = 100,
    triggerLevel = 5
} streamBufferParams;

Logger::Logger()
{
   Logger::streamBuffer = xStreamBufferCreate(totalStreamBufferBytes, triggerLevel);

    // create a task
    if (pdPASS != xTaskCreate(Logger::Process, "PROCESS_LOG", 256, this, 5, &Logger::loggerThread))
    {
        // error handle
    }
}

// uart.cpp
static Uart* pInstance;

extern "C" {
    void UARTE0_UART0_IRQHandler(void)
    {
       // ...
       if (rxIrqEnabled && dataRxd)
       {
           pInstance->setEvent(NRF_UART_EVENT_RXDRDY, 0); // disable event -- DOESN'T SEEM TO WORK AS EXPECTED WHEN SCHEDULER RUNS!
       }
     
    }
} 

Uart::Uart()
{
   pInstance = this;
   // ...
}

// main.c
int main(void)
{
   Logger logger;
   Uart uart;
   clockInit();
   vTaskStartScheduler();
}
```

**Edit:**
MCU = nRF52 which uses cortex M4

To clarify the situation further, the `NRF_UART_EVENT_RXDRDY` doesn't get RESET at all when the scheduler runs whereas when no scheduler is involved, IRQ works as expected i.e `NRF_UART_EVENT_RXDRDY` does get reset

Comment: Where do you clear the interrupt flag? Looks like you’re only clearing the interrupt source enable.

Comment: What processor?  Even if it's yet another ARM Cortex M core, the actual interrupt structure depends on the peripherals.

Comment: You need to do something to clear the UART RX interrupt flag or the micro will just continuously vector back to the interrupt handler. Typically you'd clear the RX flag by reading data from the RX register to ensure that it's empty and ready for the next byte. Some micros might want you to 'manually' clear the flag in addition to reading the RX data register.

Comment: @Kartman I reckon that's what I'm only supposed to disable anyways. As mentioned, everything works fine with no scheduler running

Comment: If you’re using a nrf52 (cortex m4) then interrupt priorities come into play with freertos. It would be wise to read up about the cm3/4 interrupt system as it is quite sophisticated. I got caught out by it which forced me to research.  Nevertheless, turning of the int enable is the isr is fraught with danger. Like @brhans mentions, you must clear the source. See https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/arm-cortex-m-exceptions-and-nvic

Comment: I am still confused. In the debugger, I see the flag i'm trying to disable doesn't get disabled at all...and if it's not, it makes sense for the IRQ to keep firing. So the question really is, what's preventing the register to not disable when the scheduler is running?

Comment: You want to clear the flag, not disable it - a flag is not a switch! My NRF52 fu is shaky, but you probably need to write a '1' bit to the flag to clear it.

Comment: you're still misunderstanding the main concern I feel. It's less about the flag/interrupt and more about it not being set ONLY when the scheduler runs. I have a suspicion there's a stack overflow but don't know how to trace it

Comment: If I remember correctly, freeRtos paints the stacks with a value. You can examine the memory before and after to see if the painted value gets wiped. You can also see how much stack is actually being used. Look at the map file to see where the stacks are located.

Comment: what's the way of accessing something that's defined inside `main` in the watcher once the scheduler has run? Currently, it can't find the symbol cause the current execution is no longer in main